# Ideas for a "Now" icon

Tags: icons, image, dates, time

Next to a date/time-picker field, what would a "Now" icon look like? I can't find any good ideas.

The "Now" icon would be alongside a "Today" icon. When clicked, it would populate the field with the current date and time (the today icon would only populate the field with today's date).

Comment: What does your "Today" icon look like?

Comment: I don't have it either as I'm waiting to know what a "Now" icon looks like. But I would imagine "Today" would look like a flip calendar, akin to http://findicons.com/icon/168805/date?id=336335 or http://findicons.com/icon/234326/korganizer?id=329878.

Comment: I'd prefer not to need any text on this icon, but I'm baffled about doing without.

Comment: Per site description, asking about icons is off topic. Check out the [help] and [about] pages to learn more about getting the most out of this community!

Comment: Too bad. It turned out to be a popular question. At least I got my answer.

Comment: It was a UX question for my team. We'd bring in usability and designers to hash it out. Why the haters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (dead) simple alternative might be a set of two buttons, one labeled "now" and the other labeled "today".  Basic OS generated buttons can be replaced with a fancier button graphic, but the text of the button says it all with no confusion.  I think this is good "Don't make me think" design - an icon works well for certain things, but abstract ideas like "now" are hard to capture in a graphic.  Icons may leave people confused about their purpose or worst case, unclear that they are interactive.  Everybody knows what to do with a button, and they know what "now" and "today" mean without any mental effort.

Answer (score 2):

"Now" icon could be clock with small label "Now", "Today" icon - calendar with day of today, but I prefer text-labeled buttons instead icons.

Answer (score 1):

The best icons out there for 'today' seem to just be a calandar with the word 'today' inside it. Having both next to each other, and displaying each one in an abstract image, while keeping the difference between the two clear, sounds extremely difficult or unlikely.

I think your best course of action is to simply have two buttons labeled 'today' and 'now'.

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime picker has default value as current date and time you can use several metaphors and adapt appropriate icons of them, e.g.:

- RESET, means *Reset Date value to Today and Time value to Now*
- CLEAR, means *Clear any editing of Date and Time and return initial Today/Now values*
- SET TO DEFAULT, *Set Date and Time values to their defaults - Today and Now*

After finding appropriate icon adjust it using calendar as background for date and clock as background for time.

This is not ideal solution but just one more direction of thinking.